# Proximity Alert not triggering

Tags: android, android-intent, location, android-pendingintent, proximity

I'm having some trouble getting my proximity alert to work on my Android app that's running on an Emulator. Basically the proximity alert should start an activity that will (for now) print to the log, however when a desired location is set for the alert, and the emulator's location is set at that particular location, nothing happens. Here is the code for the proximity alert:

```
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
PendingIntent proxIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MapActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);

lm.addProximityAlert(latlng.latitude, latlng.longitude, 100, -1, proxIntent);
```

Now MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT is declared in the manifest as stated below:

```
<receiver android:name=".myLocationReceiver">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="PROXIMITY_ALERT"/>
   </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And here is my code for myLocationReceiver

```
public class myLocationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private static final String TAG = "myLocationReceiver";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    final String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
    final Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

    if(entering) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: Entering proximity of location");
    }

}
```

}

I believe my problem has something to do with the Intent or PendingIntent object but I'm not entirely sure. Also I have heard that usually the GPS will take about a minute to actually register the proximity, but I still do not get a log message even after some time.

Thanks!

Comment: the emulator doesn't have a sensor...  have you tried installing it on an actual device?

Comment: @me_ The emulator has location services where you can send longitude and latitude to the phone, is this different than the sensor you're referring to?

Comment: it's just a guess...   but before tearing the code apart, have you installed it on an actual device?

Answer (score 0):

You've created an `Intent` with action `MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT` and then used `PendingIntent.getActivity()` to get a `PendingIntent` to pass to the `LocationManager`. When the proximity conditions are satisfied, `LocationManager` will try to start an **`Activity`** that is listening for action `MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT`.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
PendingIntent proxIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MapActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

In your manifest, you've declared a `BroadcastReceiver` that is listening for action `MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT`. This won't work.

Since you want the proximity alert to trigger a `BroadcastReceiver`, you need to get the `PendingIntent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MY_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
PendingIntent proxIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MapActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

Personally, I think it would be better to use an "explicit" `Intent` instead of an "implicit" `Intent`. In that case you would do it like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, myLocationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent proxIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MapActivity.this, 0, intent, 0);
```

You don't need to use the ACTION in the `Intent`.

Using an "explicit" `Intent` tells Android exactly what component (class) to launch. If you use an "implicit" `Intent`, Android has to search for components that advertise that they can handle certain ACTIONs.